# Cannot remove English keyboard option from language bar

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language-bar

I use the language bar to switch between Chinese and French keyboards. However lately an English keyboard option also appeared in the popup. I didn't add it myself and I cannot find any way to remove it. For some reasons, it doesn't show up in the Settings page (see screenshot below). Any idea what could be the reason?

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

This is what I have in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\keyboard layout\Preload
    1    REG_SZ    0000040c
    2    REG_SZ    00000804
    3    REG_SZ    e0200804
    4    REG_SZ    e0210804

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\keyboard layout\Substitutes
    0000040c    REG_SZ    a001040c

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\keyboard layout\Toggle
    Language Hotkey    REG_SZ    1
    Hotkey    REG_SZ    1
    Layout Hotkey    REG_SZ    3
```

Comment: What about adding and removing again?

Comment: @week, thanks for suggestion, however I just tried and it didn't work. When I've added it, the keyboard showed up in the Settings page, however when I removed it, it stayed in the language bar.

Comment: Post here what you have in registry under `HKCU\Keyboard Layout\` in keys `preload` and `Substitutes`. Run `cmd.exe` and type `reg query "hkcu\keyboard layout" /s`

Comment: @week, I've posted the registry info, can you see any issue in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is missing US keyboard. Run this command from cmd.exe or add value below to registry. Then open `taskmgr` (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd>), kill process explorer.exe and by "File" -> "New task" start again. Then remove US keyboard, the option will be there.

`reg add "hkcu\keyboard layout\Preload" /v 5 /t REG_SZ /d 00000405`

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\keyboard layout\Preload
    5    REG_SZ    00000405